# How to expose 2 ports in OpenShift for JMeter client

Tags: jmeter, openshift

I built a Docker image which provides an JMeter server. In the Dockerfile I exposed 2 ports by

`[...]
EXPOSE 1099 50000
[...]`

When running the image on my local machine with

`docker run --rm --name [name] -d -p 1099:1099 -p 50000:50000 [name]`

I can access the server from the JMeter controller.

When I try to run the image in OpenShift I cannot find a way to expose the 2 ports in the Route's definition. It seems as if only one port per Route is allowed.

Is there a work around in OpenShift to access the JMeter server from my client analogous to my local setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/16529) to support multiple ports per route in OpenShift

> Is it possible for a route to expose multiple ports? #16529

There's a workaround to defined multiple routes for different ports

> To have multiple routers for different ports, copy router YAML, change every occurence of port and router name, and import the YAML as a new router.
>
> @tocosonic This way you can use the same host for different routes (because, different ports will be served by different routers)

Comment: I should mention that I only have access to OpenShift as developer which means I only can create Routes but not routers. @user7294900 is there a way to configure Routes in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have created one route with following

```
oc expose srv foo --port 8080 --hostname foo.bar.com
```

This will take service name and use it also for route name and expose the service

> oc get routes
>
> NAME .   HOST/PORT .          SERVICES .       PORT .
>   foo .    foo.bar.com .        foo .            8080

suppose you want to create another route at port 9000; if you run following command

```
oc expose srv foo --port 9000 --hostname api.foo.bar.com
```

You will get following error
Error from server (AlreadyExists): "foo" already exist
As you can see the command took srv name and used it for route name as well

Instead, you can do following to provide unique route name

```
oc expose srv foo --port 900 --hostname api.foo.bar.com --name api
```

Name of the service must be unique, and since by default service name is used for route name as well, another route request raises exception.

You can avoid this exception by providing a unique name with **--name**

Comment: This won't work in openshift - HostAlreadyClaimed error